# Why isn't it allowed to implement methods of a base interface explicitely on the derived interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

This is a simplified example to explain my issue - I am trying to improve the code readability for an explicitely implemented generic interface by deriving the generic interface to an interface with a concrete type like this: `interface ITyped : IGeneric<string>`. The idea is to not have to use `IGeneric<string>` in all the implemented explicit method names.

So the code would read:

```
ITyped.M1(string p){}
ITyped.M2(string p){}
```

instead of

```
IGeneric<string>.M1(string p){}
IGeneric<string>.M2(string q){}
```

Imagine an interface with multiple generic types to understand why I'm trying this.

Now the thing is: this won't work! The compiler throws an Error that my declaration is not a member of the interface. I have to explicitely use the base interface with the generic declaration. Wouldn't it make sense if this worked? Further tries revealed that not even generics are required - a simple derived interface also doesn't allow to explicitely implement an inherited method of the base interface in the derived interface. I'd like to understand the theory why it wasn't allowed.

Is there an alternative to improve the readability for this scenario?

Complete example code here:

```
interface IGeneric<T>
{
    void M(T t);
}

interface ITyped: IGeneric<string> { }

class C : ITyped
{
    //Explicit declaration with base interface - OK
    void IGeneric<string>.M(string t) {}

    //Implicit declaration - OK
    public void M(string t){ }

    //Explicit declaration with derived interface - Error!
    void ITyped.M(string t) {} //Error CS0539   

}
```

Comment: The [C# 5.0 langauge specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) spells out this behavior in section 13.4.1, as an FYI. It may be helpful to read through all of 13.4, as well.

Comment: I think supporting this at the CLR level would have fixed the readonly collection interfaces enabling the old mutable interfaces to extend the new readonly interfaces. So it's certainly a feature with significant advantages.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thanks for the chapters - I think the right chapter to read would be 13.4.4 - Namely the example with multiple derived interfaces on page 397. Imagine you had 2 derived interfaces and you would implement them both explicitely in your class, you would be able to implement 2 non distinct behaviours of the base interface method, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a hint to the c# language spec and CodesInChaos comment on another answer, I was able to find a reason why it would not be allowed:

Imagine a second derived interface, `IDerived2: IBase` and a concrete class which would implement both derived interfaces, I'd be able to create two ambiguous implementations

```
private interface IBase
{
    void M();
}

class C : IDerived1, IDerived2
{
    //Which method should now be called when using IBase.M?
    void IDerived1.M() {} 
    void IDerived2.M() {}  
}
```

So it is multiinheritance which restrains us to make use of a derived explicit interface declaration. By forcing the use of the base declaration, in case of multiinheritance the compiler assures that there can be only one implementation and so effectively preventing us from doing something bad.

The workaround would be to *not* explicitely implement the interface but to do it implicitely - there is actually another reason why I did it explicitely but in general, implicit declaration would be an effective work around.

Comment: But **only** when explicitly implemented. With implicit implementation of M, you would essentially be providing the same implementation to satisfy the derived interfaces `IDerived1` and `IDerived2` and would be able to successfully cast and use such objects as those interface types.

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
IGeneric<string> x = new C();
```

If `C` does not implement M from `IGeneric<T>` it would not be possible to keep the interface assignable from the class.

Comment: @BenAaronson The question is why you cannot create an explicit declaration off of a derived interface when the method is declared in a base interface.  This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @BenAaronson I don't see how it answers the question at all. The actual answer should be related to multiple inheritance creating ambiguities if multiple base interfaces implement a method. I also thing there are some brittle base-class related problems.

Comment: @juharr If the next line after the one in this answer was `x.M("")`, the compiler would have no way of picking an implementation of `M` to use. It only has an implementation for `ITyped.M`, and the static type of x would not be assignable to `ITyped`, so it'd be inappropriate to use that implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That may be an additional reason, though I'd probably need a fuller explanation to know exactly what you mean. This answer is a legitimate reason too, though.

Comment: @BenAaronson I don't see how this answer is valid. The OP proposes that implementing `ITyped.M` explicitly should implement `IGeneric<string>.M`, so tim's example wouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @CodesInChaos  But the whole point of explicit interface implementation is that it doesn't do dynamic dispatch. That's why if you do both implicit and explicit implementation of an interface member on the same class, then call that member, the result you get depends on the *static* type you have the class assigned to

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thinking about it, your reason is clearer though. Probably worth writing as an answer.

Comment: @BenAaronson just to clarify: the example was just to give the different ways I was successful or failed - it wasn't the idea to have them in parallel but each exclusively - although it's interesting to consider the implications when you see them side by side.